# View a constraints source in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone tell me how to view the source of a constraint in SQL Server?

I have a table with a check constraint, when I do an insert I am violating the constraint. I would like to know what the constraint is so I can avoid this, but can only get the name of the constraint.

I have looked it up in sys.objects, but this did not contain anything of use.

Thanks

Comment: Look in management studio under the table / constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the constraint details in the more focused, more appropriate system catalog view `sys.check_constraints` (`sys.objects` contains only very minimal info) when you have it's name:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.check_constraints
WHERE Name = 'your-name-here'
```

The column that's most interesting to you will be the `definition` which defines what that constraint does, e.g. what range or list of values is acceptable

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
       cc.name
     , cc.[definition]
FROM sys.check_constraints cc
WHERE cc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.your_table')
```